# How to wrap all HTML-Code after <span class="xy"> until next occurence of </p>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wrapall, nextuntil

```
<p class="bodytext">
    <span class="datum">19.11.2015:</span>Some text <a href="path/to/link" title="some title" class="download">Some text</a>. Again some text!
</p>
<p class="bodytext">
    <span class="datum">19.11.2015:</span>Maybe also only some text.
</p>
<p class="bodytext">
    <span class="datum">19.11.2015:</span><a href="path/to/link" title="some title" class="download">Only with link</a>
</p>
```

Should be after jQuery:

```
<p class="bodytext">
    <span class="datum">19.11.2015:</span>
    <div class="someClass">Some text <a href="path/to/link" title="some title" class="download">Some text</a>. Again some text!</div>
</p>
<p class="bodytext">
    <span class="datum">19.11.2015:</span>
    <div class="someClass">Maybe also only some text.</div>
</p>
<p class="bodytext">
    <span class="datum">19.11.2015:</span>
    <div class="someClass"><a href="path/to/link" title="some title" class="download">Only with link</a></div>
</p>
```

So all HTML-Code after the `</span>` should be wrapped in a div until the next occurence of `</p>`

What I tried:

```
$(".datum").each(function (index) {
        $(this).nextUntil("p").andSelf().wrapAll("<div class='someClass' />");
    });
```

Or:

```
$(".datum").nextUntil("p").wrap('<div class="someClass" />');
```

Didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: You can make use of **[wrapInner](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/)** to wrap div around content of `bodytext` div and then take out `datum` span from wrapped div.

```js
$(function(){
    $('p.bodytext').each(function(){
    
      $(this).wrapInner( "<div class='someClass'></div>");
      $(this).prepend($(this).find('div.someClass').find('span.datum'));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="bodytext">
    <span class="datum">19.11.2015:</span>Some text <a href="path/to/link" title="some title" class="download">Some text</a>. Again some text!
</p>
<p class="bodytext">
    <span class="datum">19.11.2015:</span>Maybe also only some text.
</p>
<p class="bodytext">
    <span class="datum">19.11.2015:</span><a href="path/to/link" title="some title" class="download">Only with link</a>
</p>
```

**EDIT**: - As OP wants to put filter on `bodytext`containing child `datum` span. Here you can use [:has](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector for `bodytext`. Also you can use [:contains](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) or [.has()](https://api.jquery.com/has/) jQuery methods.

```js
$(function(){
    $('p.bodytext:has(span.datum)').each(function(){
    
      $(this).wrapInner( "<div class='someClass'></div>");
      $(this).prepend($(this).find('div.someClass').find('span.datum'));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="bodytext">
    <span>19.11.2015:</span>Some text <a href="path/to/link" title="some title" class="download">Some text</a>. Again some text!
</p>
<p class="bodytext">
    <span class="datum">19.11.2015:</span>Maybe also only some text.
</p>
<p class="bodytext">
    <span class="datum">19.11.2015:</span><a href="path/to/link" title="some title" class="download">Only with link</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Works perfect, thanks! Just one thing might be optimized: It now changes all p.bodytext, even on other pages. But I only want it to change p.bodytext with preceeding span.datum. I solved it by assigning an ID to the main div on that page, but would be nice without.

Comment: Yes, you can definitely filter the bodytext on the basis of child element datum span. See my edit in answer.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$('.bodytext').find('*').not('span').wrap('<div class="someClass" />')
```

Comment: Thanks! But wraps only HTML tags like <a> but not all the other free floating text...
`<p class="bodytext">
    <span class="datum">19.11.2015:</span>Some text <div class="someClass"><a href="path/to/link" title="some title" class="download">Some text</a></div>. Again some text!
</p>`

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong, because, the code append div element after the element that has class "datum" until `<p>` element is start. But in div with class="bodytext" you have no `<p>` element.

Try this;

```
$(".bodytext").each(){
    $(this).after($(".datum")).wrapAll("<div class='someClass'>Some text <a href='path/to/link' title='some title' class='download'>Some text</a>. Again some text!</div>");
}
```

I'm not sure about wrapAll, but the order is true for the append operation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an aproach that is faster than any full jQuery solution.

It fecthes the first element, removes it and re-creates the content with the remaining content left.

Here's what I mean:

```js
$(function(){
  
 $('.bodytext').each(function(){
  var first = this.children[0];
  this.removeChild(first);
  this.innerHTML = first.outerHTML + '<div class="someclass">' + this.innerHTML + '</div>';
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="bodytext">
    <span class="datum">19.11.2015:</span>Some text <a href="path/to/link" title="some title" class="download">Some text</a>. Again some text!
</p>
<p class="bodytext">
    <span class="datum">19.11.2015:</span>Maybe also only some text.
</p>
<p class="bodytext">
    <span class="datum">19.11.2015:</span><a href="path/to/link" title="some title" class="download">Only with link</a>
</p>
```

The `outerHTML` property contains the whole HTML of the input, including:

- `name`
- `id`
- `class`
- `data-*`
- `on<event>`
- ... any attribute directly set into the HTML

  Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks very much! But doesn't seem to work exactly in the way, that I need it. It changes only the first of all occurences of p.bodytext.

Comment: @user3532637 That's impossible. If you check the final source code on my stack snippet, using an element inspector, you will see that the output is the one you want

Comment: Yes, works in a sandbox, but in my environment it's as I described (maybe because there are some further `<p class="bodytext">` tags in between), so it might be a solution for future visitors. So thank you very much for your input!